# XOR on tensors (using vectorization) having float value in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, vectorization, xor, bitwise-xor

I have two tensors t1 and t2 of the same shape (in my case [64, 64, 3]). I need to compute the XOR of these two tensors. But couldn't figure out a way to do so.

```
import bitstring
from bitstring import *

@tf.function
def xor(x1, x2) :
  a = BitArray(float=x1, length = 64)
  b = BitArray(float=x2, length = 64)
  a ^= b
  return a.float
```

This `xor` function computes xor of two float values in python.

Sample input tensors are,

```
t1 = tf.constant([[1.1, 2.2, 3.3],
                  [4.4, 5.5, 6.6]], dtype=tf.float64)
t2 = tf.constant([[7.7, 8.8, 9.9],
                  [10.1, 11.11, 12.12]], dtype=tf.float64)
```

I can't seem to find a way to compute `xor` of two tensors.

1. How can I write **vectorized version of the `xor`** function call which will compute xor of each pair of floats from two tensors of **any shape** (similar to tf.add, tf.matmul etc)? I tried `np.vectorized` etc.
2. How can I **efficiently write the `xor` function**? In order to use the gpu in tensorflow I need to write each statement using `tf.something` e.g. tf.add, tf. matmul etc. But since tensorflow doesn't have native support of `Bitstring`, is there any way to convert float to bitstring in tensorflow (in the `xor` function) so that I can execute `tf.bitwise_xor` over that later?

Comment: What's your expected output for XOR on floats? I thought it was only between `0` and `1`

Comment: XOR of two floats would be another float as per my understanding. It would not be possible directly compute xor on floats, so we need to convert it to a bitstring and compute xor over that. 

Actually I want to compute `A xor B = C`, later to get A from C, I can simply do `C xor B` which is equal to A.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, taking the xor of two float values as bit arrays produces a garbage 64-bit value that cannot be interpreted as floats.  That should be obvious; you're smashing the exponent and ruining the mantissa.  It's true that you can reproduce either value by xoring the other back in, but is that really useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need a custom C++ op to do this. The [Tensorflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/create_op) have a nice tutorial on how to construct one. Here's an example to get you started.

**`xor_op.cc`**

```cpp
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/common_shape_fns.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/shape_inference.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_types.h"

namespace tensorflow {
using shape_inference::InferenceContext;

REGISTER_OP("Xor")
    .Input("input_tensor_a: float")
    .Input("input_tensor_b: float")
    .Output("output_tensor: float")
    .SetShapeFn([](InferenceContext* c) {
      return shape_inference::UnchangedShapeWithRankAtLeast(c, 1);
    });

class XorOp : public OpKernel {
 public:
  explicit XorOp(OpKernelConstruction* ctx) : OpKernel(ctx) {}

  float XorFloats(const float* a, const float* b, float* c) {
    *(int*)c = *(int*)a ^ *(int*)b;
    return *c;
  }

  void Compute(OpKernelContext* ctx) override {
    // get input tensors
    const Tensor& input_fst = ctx->input(0);
    const Tensor& input_snd = ctx->input(1);

    TTypes<float, 1>::ConstFlat c_in_fst = input_fst.flat<float>();
    TTypes<float, 1>::ConstFlat c_in_snd = input_snd.flat<float>();

    // allocate output tensor
    Tensor* output_tensor = nullptr;
    OP_REQUIRES_OK(ctx,
                   ctx->allocate_output(0, input_fst.shape(), &output_tensor));

    auto output_flat = output_tensor->flat<float>();
    const int N = c_in_fst.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
      XorFloats(&c_in_fst(i), &c_in_snd(i), &output_flat(i));
    }
  }
};

REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("Xor").Device(DEVICE_CPU), XorOp);

}  // namespace tensorflow
```

Let's build the op and test

```sh
$ TF_LFLAGS=($(python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(" ".join(tf.sysconfig.get_link_flags()))'))
$ TF_CFLAGS=($(python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(" ".join(tf.sysconfig.get_compile_flags()))'))
$ 
$ g++ -std=c++14 -shared xor_op.cc -o xor_op.so -fPIC ${TF_CFLAGS[@]} ${TF_LFLAGS[@]} -O2
```

Let's run the op and see if it works.

**`main.py`**

```py
import tensorflow as tf


def main():
    xor_module = tf.load_op_library("./xor_op.so")
    xor_op = xor_module.xor

    # make some data
    a = tf.constant(
        [[1.1, 2.2, 3.3], [4.4, 5.5, 6.6]],
        dtype=tf.float32)

    b = tf.constant(
        [[7.7, 8.8, 9.9], [10.1, 11.11, 12.12]],
        dtype=tf.float32)
    
    c = xor_op(a, b)

    print(f"a: {a}")
    print(f"b: {b}")
    print(f"c: {c}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

# a: [[1.1 2.2 3.3]
#     [4.4 5.5 6.6]]
# b: [[ 7.7   8.8   9.9 ]
#     [10.1  11.11 12.12]]
# c: [[3.3319316e+38 2.3509887e-38 3.7713776e-38]
#     [6.3672620e-38 4.7666294e-38 5.3942895e-38]]
```

Cool. Let's test a little more rigorously.

**`test.py`**

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.platform import test as test_lib


class XorOpTest(test_lib.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # import the custom op
        xor_module = tf.load_op_library("./xor_op.so")
        self._xor_op = xor_module.xor

        # make some data
        self.a = tf.constant(
            [[1.1, 2.2, 3.3], [4.4, 5.5, 6.6]],
            dtype=tf.float32)

        self.b = tf.constant(
            [[7.7, 8.8, 9.9], [10.1, 11.11, 12.12]],
            dtype=tf.float32)

    def test_xor_op(self):
        c = self._xor_op(self.a, self.b)
        self.assertAllEqual(self._xor_op(c, self.b), self.a)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_lib.main()

# [ RUN      ] XorOpTest.test_xor_op
# [       OK ] XorOpTest.test_xor_op
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Ran 1 test in 0.005s
# 
# OK
```

I'll leave it to you to extend this to work on a GPU.
If you're curious, the `XorFloats` method comes from a bit level manipulation used in the [inverse square root problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root#Overview_of_the_code).

Comment: Thanks for the write-up. I am having trouble when building this in google colab. “fatal error: tensorflow/core/framework/common_shape_fns.h: No such file or directory”. Any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: Tensorflow version: 2.4.1

Comment: "I am having trouble when building this in google colab." This seems unnecessarily complicated. Just build it on a linux command line with tensorflow installed. I used gcc 8.3.0, python 3.7.10, and tensorflow 2.4.1.

Comment: Thanks, I built it in my local machine and uploaded in colab. Now it is working, as you have also pointed out.

Comment: If you ***need*** to build it in colab, you can do it like this:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1c7IdWX-tpHJWBLaxD2Mj5mSezKqkZlUA?usp=sharing

Comment: Absolutely. I have already upvoted and accepted your answer. But the upvote is not showing publicly since my reputation point is less than 15. I hope it will show soon.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a caution about trying to use the result of an xor between two floats in a context that actually expects floats.

```
import struct

x = 1.0
y = 3.5
x1 = list(struct.pack('d', x ))
y1 = list(struct.pack('d', y ))
print('x1', x1)
print('y1', y1)

z1 = [a^b for a,b in zip(x1,y1)]
print('z1', z1)

z1 = bytes(z1)
z = struct.unpack('d',z1)[0]
print('z',z)
```

Output:

```
C:\tmp>python x.py
x1 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 240, 63]
y1 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 64]
z1 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 252, 127]
z nan

C:\tmp>
```

Comment: The OP is asking for a solution in Tensorflow.

Comment: Understood.  I'm trying to point out that, after passing through the XOR process, what you get is no longer a legal floating point number.  I'm suggesting that there must be a better way to achieve his goal.

Comment: If comments provided a way to format blocks of code, I would have done so.  This is the only mechanism this site provides.